# Convert Markup Extension Shorthand Syntax to Full Xml Form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I have XAML string like:

```
    <Button Content={Binding Name} Style={StaticResource ButtonStyle}/>
```

How I can convert all braces to elements in code like:

```
    <Button>
      <Button.Content>
         <Binding Path="Name">
      </Button.Content>
      <Button.Style>
         <StaticResource ResourceKey="ButtonStyle"/>
      </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: It would have helped if you had explained what you are trying to achieve, so we knew why you want to do the conversion.

Comment: I think it is an interesting topic, but can you show what you have tried so far to solve the problem yourself? The markup extension syntax is well-defined by Microsoft, so what is it in particular you are stuck at?

Comment: By the way, your example illustrates the desired conversion, but it contains a few syntax errors.

Comment: I need to create parser which read resource dictionary generated from Zam3D and change the xaml-file (change structure) to open it (as xml) in my program. The program serializing xml to native objects (not Controls or UIElements)

Comment: I need way to read the data as XmlElement or XElement but I can't do it correctly for data between braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XamlReader` and `XamlWriter` which I think(!) by default does not save the shorthand variety. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

which includes an example

```
// Create the Button.
Button originalButton = new Button();
originalButton.Height = 50;
originalButton.Width = 100;
originalButton.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
originalButton.Content = "Click Me";

// Save the Button to a string. 
string savedButton = XamlWriter.Save(originalButton);

// Load the button
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedButton);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Button readerLoadButton = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

saved button above looks like

```
 <Button Background="#FFF0F8FF" Width="100" Height="50" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">Click Me</Button>
```

Comment: This is the only real answer to the question so far.